# How to Ubuntu 16.04 with FFMPEG + NVENC?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

Помогите скомпилировать FFMPEG с поддержкой NVENC на Ubuntu 16.04

```
Driver version nvidia: 390+
Video codec SDK: 8.1
ffmpeg: last from git
ffnvcodec: +
```

> Использую такую конфигурацию, но что то пока не выходит..
>
> Компиляция происходит без участия nvenc акселлератора :\

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-cuda
make -j$(nproc)
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=FFmpeg --fstrans=no --backup=no --pkgversion="$(date +%Y%m%d)-git" --deldoc=yes
```

Задача везде так услажнена, что я прямо не знаю где я сбиваюсь с толку, особенно это касается видимо то части где я совсем незнаком со сборкой софта на unix

> ```
> ffmpeg -hwaccels
> ```
>
> Hardware acceleration methods:
>   vdpau,
>   cuda,
>   vaapi,
>   cuvid

Answer (score -1):

мне помогло это:
[Minimalist static FFmpeg build on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nvidia NVENC enabled](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/988473b79fd5c8f0db54b92ebb47387a)

в по ссылке пошаговая инструкция с примерами конфигурации файла сборки.

только исходники ffmpeg брал с сайта ffmpeg.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Одной ссылки для этого не достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ. Он очен ценен для меня.
Я обезательно воспользуюсь вашим советом.